# Import Dynamic Excel into SQL 2008 r2

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, sql-server-2008, import

I am importing an excel file into SQL 2008 r2 using a linked server. The column names will always be different. The only thing that is consistent is the file name and the sheet name.

I have attached what the import looks like.
[image]

I need to take this raw data loop over it and import into a table:

```
INSERT INTO importholding(prodcode, width, height, price)
```

The values of prodcode would be something like 'ab30012' (ab+a2+b1), width would be 012, height would be 30, price would be 34.50. This would be one record in the table.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Can you add another sheet and use Excel formulae to get the data on the sheet in the right 4 columns (Prod, Width, Height, Price)?

Comment: If that is a possibility I am all for it. Do you know of a way to parse the data so that I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @columns nvarchar(max)
SELECT @columns = ISNULL(@columns+',','') + QUOTENAME([name]) FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('MyTable') AND [column_id] > 1 ORDER BY [column_id]

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)
SET @sql = N'SELECT ''ab''+LTRIM(STR([000]))+REPLACE(STR([b],3),'' '',''0'') AS [prodcode], [000] AS [height], [b] AS [width], [price] FROM MyTable UNPIVOT([price] FOR [b] IN ('+@columns+')) p'

INSERT INTO importholding(prodcode, width, height, price)
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Your code example is throwing an "Incorrect syntax near 'price' error. Any idea what is causing this?

Comment: Which line is throwing the error?  Did you change 'MyTable' to the name of your import table?

Comment: SSMS is saying the error is on line 1 which means absolutely nothing. I think the error is coming from the unpivot part of the statement. I changed 'MyTable' to 'Book1$' which is the excel spreadsheet that is read via a linked server.